# JavaScript - Do something every n seconds

Tags: javascript, html, intervals

I am fairly new to JavaScript, and I am learning it through p5 and videos by Daniel Shiffman.

I've been looking for a way to update a program every minute or so that checks a weather api, so I don't have to refresh the page myself.

I am aware that there are already answers to this question on here, but none of them make sense to me, as I am very new to JS.

So if you could answer it with an ELI5 ("Explain it like I'm five") description that would great.

Comment: Javascript timers would be a perfect choice here...Check setinterval and settimeout

Comment: Have you read up on `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()`?

Comment: See [*MDN: JavaScript timers*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - Try to write some code yourself and people will help you with it

Comment: You can use either `setTimeout` or `setInterval` based on your need as I explained the difference a bit below :-)

Comment: @JaromandaX - user's profile calls out they're in high school. They're new to the site, new to the field. Find something better to do than bully people curious about our craft. 3+ people here said the same thing without being jerks - try to learn something from them. Don't be such a Diesel 10.

Answer (score 37):

`setInterval()` is your easiest option.

Take a look at this simple example:

```
// Will execute myCallback every 0.5 seconds 
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 500);

function myCallback() {
 // Your code here
}
```

More information and more examples can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 14):

In plain vanilla Javascript, you would use setInterval:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(checkWeatherAPI, 60000);

function checkWeatherAPI() {
  // go check API 
  console.log("checking weather API");
}
```

If you were to run the above, the callback function: checkWeatherAPI, would run once every minute, or 60,000 milliseconds forever, full documentation here: [WindwTimers.setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

To stop the interval you would simply run this line:

```
window.clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Answer (score 4):

Choosing whether `setInterval` OR `setTimeout` is based on your need and requirement as explained a bit about the difference below.

`setInterval` will be called irrespective of the time taken by the API. For an instance you set an API call every 5 seconds and your API call is taking 6 seconds due to the network latency or server latency, the below `setInterval` will trigger the second API call before the first API completes.

```
var timer = setInterval(callAPI, 5000);

function callAPI() {
  // TO DO
  triggerXhrRequest(function(success){

  });
}
```

Instead, if you want to trigger another API call after 5 seconds once the first API call completed, you can better use `setTimeout` as below.

```
var timer = setTimeout(callAPI, 5000);

function callAPI() {
  // TO DO
  triggerXhrRequest(function(success){
      timer = setTimeout(callAPI, 5000);
  });
}
```

`setTimeout` will be called once after `n`th seconds. So you can control when the next one can be called as above.

**MDN Documentation**

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score 2):

```
function doThings() {
   // The things I want to do (or increment)
}

setTimeout(doThings, 1000); // Milliseconds
```